# Unconditional appearance of google sign-in popup HTML/JS (in an ASP.NET webforms application)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, integration, google-signin, credentials

I am implementing a Google sign-in (using HTML/JS) in my ASP.NET webforms application, as follows:

```
<div id="authorize">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/> // regular sign-in
    <div id="g_id_onload" 
        data-client_id="CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-context: "signup"
        data-ux_mode ="popup"
        data-size="large"
        data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
        data-auto-prompt="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" 
        data-theme="filled_blue"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-size="large"
        data-text="Sign up with Google"
        data-type="standard">
    </div>
</div>
<script> 
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);
    }
    function decodeJwtResponse(data) {
        var jwtPayload = parseJwt(data);
        // console.log(email, emailVerified, familyName, givenName, locale);
    }
    function parseJwt(token) {
        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    }
</script>
```

The implementation works, while triggers an automatic popup of the google popup. I am looking for a fix that would trigger the popup only upon the google button press. In addition the google button is auto-filled with my google credentials, is it possible that it would load as instructed - `data-text="Sign up with Google"`? Thanks.